# ASP.NET MVC web site Randomly Logging Exceptions which having multiple Wordpress Path's Which are not part of hosted site at all

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, iis-7.5, error-logging

I have a website which completely built using `ASP.NET MVC c#, Javascript/JQuery` and hosted on IIS 7.5. There is no reference for `Wordpress` neither any plugin which is related to WordPress is installed as a package. We noticed that there are a variety of Exceptions are getting logged.

Below is the list of messages in exception, Not sure from where it is coming from. Please let me know if anybody comes across the same issue. Thanks

```
 The controller for path'/sito/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml' was not found or does not implement IController
 The controller for path '/cms/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml' was not found or does not implement IController
 The controller for path '/test/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml' was not found or does not implement IController
 The controller for path '/wp1/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml' was not found or does not implement IController
 The controller for path '/wordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

Comment: Do you have IIS logging enabled? You should be able to determine the IP address of the client that is hitting your site, but thinking it is a WordPress instance.

Comment: Someone, likely a robot is attempting to look for (probably insecure) WordPress installations by checking for some well known paths. Related: Not that it would  help here, but you may want to ensure your site has a robots.txt file. There's a nice nuget package for that somewhere